# Custom OG Node Type

Tags: organic-groups, nodes

I am creating a module that creates a node type. How do I declare the node type as an OG group node and other OG settings on the module install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the following code:

```
variable_set('og_content_type_usage_'. $type, 'group');
```

Comment: Excellent. All OG settings in the variable table? am I just over looking the documentation on this?

Comment: I cann't say, depend what setting do you want change...

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the content type and in 'Organic groups' section mark it as 'Group node'.

Comment: Thanks Maciej, but this is not the direction I am after.